# How do I make a pick-up for Smoke on the Water?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

As Franklin, I purchased the Smoke on the Water business. I later received a text saying:

> Hey Franklin, we've been literally burning through supplies here! I'm down a driver - do you have time to do a pick-up?

The text doesn't offer a way to respond, and they aren't a phone contact. What I can't figure out, is how to do that pick-up? I've gone to the business location in Vespucci Beach, but nothing triggers. I've checked the map, and don't see any mission indicators either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also bought it and the same happened to me. Although now after I've bought another property and they want me to do a mission for them a "P" pops up at their location. So I guess it's either bugged or it will appear later, my guess is on the first alternative.

(Edit) It seems like there is a third option; if you take too long they don't want your help anymore and send you another text "saying so". Check your phone for another text from your property.

Comment: I got a second text which was "We got a lot of unhappy stoners over here, man!". Then later today while playing, a third text finally came in, and it triggered a P (Property Management) icon where I picked up a van and delivered. Not sure if it's bugged, or just took longer than I expected.

Comment: Yeah, same happened to me today too. They texted again and now the truck is delivered. Seems all you have to do is wait (although a long time) for them to text you asking for help again!

Answer (score 2):

When u get the call from Smoke on the Water, Go to P point on the map, and follow instruction

Answer (score 0):

The "P" appears at another location at the map. (East)